# Preventing someone to generate a public key from a private one?

Tags: encryption, rsa, asymmetric

From what I read, encryption algorithms such as RSA permits to generate the public key from the private one.

Long story short, for a thesis I'm writing, I thought to solve a security issue with users editing data maliciously by giving away the private key instead of the public, and keep the public stored safely inside a database. This way, I can let my program to read a file, but I won't let the user edit it even if he could read it. As a result, I'd have a relatively reliable read-only file system (since changing permissions can be done quite easily).

But of course everything breaks apart if the user can get the public part from the private part.

I'd like to know if there is a way to prevent this (or a similiar algorithm which does the job).

EDIT: since I'm getting quite a lot of negative reviews, I'll post the full story: it's a thesis I'm writing, and the main goal is finding alternative solutions to existing problems, over than simple curiosity. Of course I knew about digital signature. Funny enough, I asked this question on stackoverflow and, other than suggesting me to post the question here, they recommended me to leave this part.

Comment: This question makes absolutley no sense whatsoever !  Do you even understand the concepts of asymmetric encryption ?  The whole point, the whole fundamental point of assymetric encryption is that the public key is PUBLIC and the private key is PRIVATE ! The PUBLIC key does not need to be "safely stored", its PUBLIC  !  If someone maliciously gives away the private key, then your key is compromised and its game over, end of story !  That is why HSMs were invented to protect private keys.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/1553/

Comment: Maybe if you give an actual example, with named users? I am having a really hard time trying to figure out how you can prevent a user from making edits to a file by giving them a private key. Are you talking about preventing a user from editing a DIFFERENT user's file, perhaps?

Comment: @Asduffo " the main goal is finding alternative solutions to existing problems" ... that may well be.  But you clearly don't understand the underlying concept of the basic principles of asymmetric cryptography.  That is why you are getting so many negative reviews, because your question just makes zero technical OR theoretical sense.  Public keys are public, private keys are private, trying to somehow reverse those roles is just nonsense. You are trying to invent the uninventable.

Comment: @LittleCode Very rude response to a valid question. If you read "public key" as "encryption key" and "private key" as "decryption key" the question makes sense.

Comment: @ErikvanVelzen Its not rude. I was just telling the facts as they are.  The terms "public key" and "private key" are well documented and have been understood for decades. The same applies to the basic principles of asymmetric cryptography. There is no need for anyone to "read differently".

Answer (score 3):

The private key should always be, well, private. As you conclude in your question, giving it away nullifies the whole point of using asymmetric encryption.

What you are looking for is a [digital signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature). You sign a file with your (secret) private key. Then anyone with your (freely distributed) public key can verify that you did in fact sign the file in its current form, and that it therefore has not been changed.

The signing consists of encrypting a hash of the file with your private key. The verification consists of decrypting the hash with the public key and checking that it is correct.

Comment: As always, an explanation for the downvote is welcome so I can learn and improve.

Comment: since you ask .... its simple.  In its present form, there is no viable answer for this question, irrespective from a technical or theoretical context, the present question is simply nonsensical.  Preventing creation of public keys ??? Keeping public keys "safe" ???  I've read that question about 10 times now and none of it makes any sense, as presently worded the question is completely against the fundamental principles of asymmetric encryption and is therefore by definition unanswerable.